# Derive DC motor formula with drum driving a conveyor belt

Tags: dc-motor, formula-derivation

The setup is a DC motor directly connected via its shaft to a drum which drives a horizontal conveyor belt. There is a load of mass, M, on the conveyor belt. 
I am stuck on trying to figure out what 'D' in the equation below means.

Title: Pulley, Conveyor Belt & Load system

Description: Load-Inertia to the motor consists of pulley (of radius r) and mass of load (M) on conveyor belt. The load-torque, to be delivered by the motor is given as:

[image: torque load]

where,

M is the mass of load on the conveyor belt.

r is the drum radius

ω = angular velocity

But i don't know what D means and i cannot figure out how that equation was derived in the first place. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you need torque to accelerate the loaded-belt. How fast must that belt speed change? All the energy of the loaded belt must come from the motor, which you provide with volts and amps into the motor.

Comment: I don't have any values to work with. I just need to understand how that formula was derived, and i cannot figure out what D means in that equation, so that makes things more complicated as i have written a few pages of equations here but i could not find a similar relation between the torque, mass, radius of drum and angular velocity/speed. It seems like D is constant?? Maybe it represents moment of inertia?

Comment: \$\small D\omega =\large \frac{d\omega}{dt}\$

Comment: It finally makes sense now. Thanks a bunch for the clarification.

Comment: Related: [Sizing a motor for a conveyor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/422211/11683).